# Gaussianity of lattice models in statistical mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

Recently there was a result on triviality (or Gaussianity) of the Ising model and $\phi^4$-theory in dimension $d=4$. This therefore holds in any dimension $d \geq 4$.
We also know that the 2D Ising model is not trivial.

However, at the same time the 2D Ising model can be mapped to the (transverse field) 1D Quantum Ising model which again can be mapped to free fermions using the Jordan-Wigner transformation. The free fermions are free and therefore Gaussian.

So these two notions of Gaussianity are obviously not the same. What can resolve my confusion?

Comment: The critical 2D Ising model may be described by a non-Gaussian (i.e. non-trivial) scalar field theory, or is may be described by a Gaussian fermion theory. The degrees of freedom in these two cases are extremely non-local in terms of each other, so one doesn't have a good reason to expect these notions to be equivalent. Note that many interesting observables of the Ising model, like spin correlators, are extremely complicated when written in the fermionic language, which is why it doesn't "look" like a conventional Gaussian theory unlike the $d\geq 4$ case.